# Blank SQL Server records when execute a soap request using .net webservice

Tags: c#, android, sql-server, web-services, soap

I'm developing an Android application to collect some data and upload them to a remote SQL Server database using a web service developed in C#.

When I test the web service it works. When I send a SOAP request from the Android application, the SOAP request is sent properly, but when I check the remote sql server database, I only find a blank record.

The function I used to build and sent the SOAP request is:

```
    String TAG="INFO000000";

    SoapObject request=new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHODNAME);

    PropertyInfo pi1=new PropertyInfo();
    pi1.setName("MenIdFK");
    pi1.setValue("4040101005");
    pi1.setType(String.class);
    request.addProperty(pi1);

    PropertyInfo pi2=new PropertyInfo();
    pi2.setName("CategAlimIdFK");
    pi2.setValue(1);
    pi2.setType(int.class);
    request.addProperty(pi2);

    PropertyInfo pi3=new PropertyInfo();
    pi3.setName("ModeAcquisIdFK");
    pi3.setValue(8);
    pi3.setType(int.class);
    request.addProperty(pi3);

    PropertyInfo pi4=new PropertyInfo();
    pi4.setName("ConsNbrFois");
    pi4.setValue(5);
    pi4.setType(int.class);
    request.addProperty(pi3);

    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    envelope.dotNet = true;
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

    HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
    androidHttpTransport.debug=true;

    try{
        androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
    } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (HttpResponseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // Logging the raw request and response (for debugging purposes)
    Log.d(TAG, "HTTP REQUEST:\n" + androidHttpTransport.requestDump);
    Log.d(TAG, "HTTP RESPONSE:\n" + androidHttpTransport.responseDump);
```

Did I miss something and is there another way to send data to the web service rather than using SOAP.

Answer (score 0):

The below link may helpful for your question using SOAP. you may get answers by google

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/88b6e5/how-to-call-web-service-in-android-using-soap/

[look here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/88b6e5/how-to-call-web-service-in-android-using-soap/)

Comment: Thank you Thomas, I found this link when I was searching a solution for my issue but my problem isn't related to the ksoap library, it's about (I think) the web service and the sql server database. I'm using Android Studio and I added the ksoap library correctly

Comment: When I execute my function I get null for String and 0 for Int

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the properties names don't match the WSDL
Thank you anyway